# Getting two different answers for a (basic) permutation problem

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

"Find the number of different signals that can be generated by arranging at least 2 flags in order (1 below the other) on a vertical staff, if 5 flags are available."

**The correct approach:**

We add the permutations of flags for each case i.e. 2 flags used, 3 flags used, till 5.

$$\sum_{k=2}^{5}{^{5}P}_{k}$$

We get $20 + 60 + 120 + 120 = 320$

**My (wrong) approach:**

Instead of considering 4 cases and adding the possible permutations, I considered *no flag* as a choice for each flag slot (let's call it $X$).

Since, we need to use at least 2 flags, $X$ is not a valid option for the first two flag slots.

The 1st slot has 5 options (any flag). The 2nd slot has 4 options (any of the 4 remaining flags).
Now the 3rd slot can have any of the 3 remaining flags, *but also $X$*, so that means 4 options.
Similarly, the 4th slot has 3 options, and 5th has 2.

The process of choosing a flag (or none) for each slot happens successively, so I assume we can multiply these numbers ($5 \times 4 \times 4 \times 3 \times 2$) getting $480$ as the answer.

Clearly I'm messing up something- what is it?

Comment: Suppose the five options for flags are A,B,C,D,E. Then you have counted the following (and similar) separately: ABCXX, ABXCX, ABXXC. Another group is ABCDX, ABCXD, ABXCD etc.  Shouldn’t they be the same?

Comment: @insipidintegrator Ohh, my mistake was ignoring the fact that if, say, the 3rd slot is not filled, the 4th slot won't be filled next, rather the next flag will go to the empty 3rd slot! Thanks!